# Delete an element in a list at a specified index

Tags: list, indexing, prolog, element

I need your help! Can you help me with this: delete an element in a list at a specified index in Prolog.

For example:

```
    delete(List,Index,NewList).   
    ?-L=[1,5,7,4],delete(L,2,L2),write(L2).
    L2 = [1,7,4]
```

I don't know how to do this.

Solved!

```
   away([G|H],1,H):-!.
   away([G|H],N,[G|L]):- N > 1, Nn is N - 1,!,away(H,Nn,L).
   ?-away([1,2,3,4,5],3,X), write(X).
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the built-in function [`nth0/4`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=nth0/4) (which uses 0-based indexing) or [`nth1/4`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=nth1/4) (which uses 0-based indexing) to do this. In your case, since you use 1-based indexing, `nth1` should be used:

```
nth1(Index, List, _, Remainder)
```

Supply `Index` and `List`, since you don't need the deleted element, you can ignore it, then the resulting list will be in `Remainder`.

This is the source code of `nth1` taken from `lists.pl` library in SWI-Prolog, rewritten to remove dependency:

```
% Case 1: Index not specified
nth1(Index, In, Element, Rest) :-
    var(Index), !,
    generate_nth(1, Index, In, Element, Rest).
% Case 2: Index is specified
nth1(Index, In, Element, Rest) :-
    integer(Index), Index > 0,
    find_nth1(Index, In, Element, Rest).

generate_nth(I, I, [Head|Rest], Head, Rest).
generate_nth(I, IN, [H|List], El, [H|Rest]) :-
    I1 is I+1,
    generate_nth(I1, IN, List, El, Rest).

find_nth1(1, [Head|Rest], Head, Rest) :- !.
find_nth1(N, [Head|Rest0], Elem, [Head|Rest]) :-
    M is N-1,
    find_nth1(M, Rest0, Elem, Rest).
```

Comment: +1. `nth1/4` also has the 1-based indexing that OP is requesting.

Comment: @mat: I think your answer is also helpful - since it shows the way to do it without library.

Comment: Thank you, but I need to do it in Strawberry Prolog or at least in Turbo Prolog. And there is no built-in functions

Comment: @Tanya: Edited to include the source code from lists.pl of SWI-Prolog. I modified it a bit to remove some functions not available in Strawberry Prolog, but not yet tested.

Comment: @nhahtdh I've just tried myself and get this: away([G|H],1,H):-!.
away([G|H],N,[G|L]):- Nn=N-1,!,away(H,Nn,L).
?-away([1,2,3,4,5],3,X), write(X). But here's an error at 2 line: No sense at line 3, after clause 1.

Comment: @Tanya: `Nn is N - 1` (test that expression on RHS evaluates to that of LHS, and with same type of integer or same type of float) rather than `Nn=N-1` (unification)

Comment: @nhahtdh Oh God. I'm so stupid! Arrr. Adding N > 1 and it works perfect! Thank you darling! xoxo

Answer (score 1):

A bit outdated, but still (especially if you wanted a bit more elegant solution):

```
del([X|XS], CNT, [X|RES]) :- NEXT is CNT - 1,
                             del(XS, NEXT, RES).
del([_|XS], 1, XS).
```

Comment: The goal `del(Xs,1,Ys)` loops. It should terminate universally.